# MVC3 how to post a list within a class in controller?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a class:

```
public class CarList
{
    public int quantity{get;set;}
    public List<Car> Cars {get;set;}
}

public class Car {
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I then create a car list with three cars in the list.  I then display info on the screen using for loop Model.Cars within a .  When I submit the form, quantity field has a valid value but Cars is null.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(CarList list)
{
    //why is list.Cars NULL when i am posting three items in the list
}
```

View:
Model = Car, added a row

Added new editor template for Car with `<tr><td>Name</td><td>Html.TextBoxFor(x=>Model.Name)</td></tr>`

And in main view:
Model = CarList, added the forloop

```
@{foreach (Car item in Model.Cars)
       {
           @Html.EditorFor(x=>item);
       }
```

Comment: How are you model binding in the controller? In other words, what does the method signature look like?

Comment: Also helps to see how you bound your inputs on the view itself.

Comment: Sorry, I looked right past it. You've already posted it. What I really need to see is your view.

Comment: It actually helps more to display the actual markup & code from your view, not bits and pieces.

Comment: so from code pointed above, you dont see any problems? cos rest is just some <div>s and html.beginform etc

Comment: What's up with your HttpPost return type. It says ActualResult instead of ActionResult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an **EditorTemplate** and you will be good.

Create a Folder Called "**EditorTemplates**" and create a view (the editor template) with the name `Car.cshtml`

[image]

Now Add the below code to this new view.

```
@model Car
<p>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
</p>
```

Now in your Main View, Use the Html.EditorFor HTML helper method to call this editor template

```
@model SO_MVC.Models.CarList
<h2>CarList</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>Quanitty </p>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.quantity) 
    @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Cars)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Now have an HTTPPOst action method to accept the form posting

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CarList(CarList model)
{
   //Check model.Cars property now.
}
```

You will see the results now 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to loop through the cars collection. You just have it like

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Cars)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the issue:

```
@foreach (Car item in Model.Cars)
       {
           @Html.EditorFor(x=>item);
       }
```

Change it to

```
@foreach (Car item in Model.Cars)
       {
           @Html.EditorFor(x=>item.Name);
       }
```

It might a case of the model binder not being smart enough to bind more than one level down, although I don't remember ever having that issue. it may also help to add [Glimpse (http://getglimpse.com/)](http://getglimpse.com/)  to your project so that you can see how the request is actually processed.