# Transfer Model Data in View to the Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a model that I am using in my view that is full of data. This data is then edited in the view. I need to figure out a way to resubmit this data back over to the controller.

Here is what I have so far.

VIEW:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadCSV", "Respondents", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FilterSet)

    <div class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="dispoCSV" onclick="$('#csvFormSubmit').click()">
        <i class="icon-file-alt"></i> Disposition Report
    </div>
    <input id="csvFormSubmit" type="submit" style="display:none;" />
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DownloadCSV(RespondentsFilterSet model)
        {
            string csv = "Charlie, Test";
            return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(csv), "text/csv", "DispositionReport.csv");
        }
```

MODEL:

```
public class RespondentsFilterSet : ColdListFilterSet
    {
        public List<int> OwningRecruiters { get; set; }

        public List<int> RecruitingGroups { get; set; }

        public override bool HasAtLeastOneFilter()
        {
            return base.HasAtLeastOneFilter() || OwningRecruiters.IsNotNullOrEmpty() || RecruitingGroups.IsNotNullOrEmpty();
        }

        public override ExpressionBase ToExpression()
        {
            var expr = base.ToExpression();

            var expressions = expr == null ? new List<ExpressionBase>() : new List<ExpressionBase> { expr };

            if (OwningRecruiters.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
            {
                expressions.Add(new InExpression<int> { Field = Create.Name<Respondent>(r => r.RecruitedBy), Values = OwningRecruiters });
            }

            if (RecruitingGroups.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
            {
                expressions.Add(new InExpression<int> { Field = Create.Name<Respondent>(r => r.RecruitingGroupId), Values = RecruitingGroups });
            }

            return expressions.Count == 0 ? null : BuildAndExpressionFromList(expressions);
        }
    }
```

I realize that my controller is not not finalized. I just have displaying some static csv. But I can't figure out why my model from my view is always null when returned to the controller.

Comment: What are the fields you are editing that is not being returned? And sometimes there is errors in the viewmodel if you want to show that to.

Comment: Posting your model may also help us identify the problem.

Comment: I am not getting any fields. its just all null. Its like as if the model coming from the view is null. which can't be the case as I can use the model quite fine in the view. @Model.FilterSet.Genders[0] works fine

Comment: Which model are you using? RespondentsFilterSet or RespondentsViewModel (controller param)

Comment: RespondentsFilterSet sorry forgot to edit that in the controller method.

Comment: mmm... RespondentsFilterSet.FilterSet doesn't exitis.

Comment: The model in my view is RespondentsViewModel. I figured since i only want the FilterSet part of that I would use that model instead. Although tried Using RespondentsViewModel as well as the RespondentsFilterSet as my data type in the controller method both still dont work for me yet.

Comment: Try to clarify your code example. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609788/mvc3-how-to-post-a-list-within-a-class-in-controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look at your form. There's not a single input element (except the submit button). You cannot expect to get anything back on the server in this case.

Please read about HTML and how forms work in HTML. In HTML forms you have input fields. Things like text fields, hidden fields, checkboxes, radio buttons, ... - fields that the user interacts with get submitted to the server.

The fact that you have made your HttpPost controller action take some model as parameter doesn't mean at all that this parameter will be initialized. In ASP.NET MVC you have a default model binder. This model binder looks at what gets sent to the server as values when the form is submitted and uses the names of the fields to bind to the corresponding properties. Without input fields in the form, nothing gets sent to the server. Just use the debugging tools built into your web browser to inspect what exactly gets sent to the server.

Contrary to classic ASP.NET WebForms, ASP.NET MVC is stateless. There's no ViewState to remember your model.

So all this rambling is to say that you should read more about HTML forms first and understand the stateless nature of the web before getting into ASP.NET MVC. As far as your particular problem is concerned, well, assuming the user is not supposed to modify any values of the view model in your view throughout some input fields, you could simply include a hidden field containing the id of your model in the form. This id will then be sent to your POST controller action as parameter and you could use it to retrieve your original model from wherever it is stored (I guess a database or something).

Comment: I inspected my HTML the HTML does indeed have a input <input id="FilterSet" name="FilterSet" type="hidden" value="QualManager.Models.RespondentsFilterSet">. But it says Qualmanager.Models.RespondentsFilterSet as my value.

Comment: Yes, which is completely meaningless. You need to have input fields for any model property. You cannot store complex things like entire models in input fields. But it is completely meaningless to have hidden input fields for every single property of your model. This doesn't make any sense. Just include a single hidden field containing the identifier of your model. Then your POST controller action will take this integer identifier as parameter and retrieve the model from wherever this model is stored (a database or something)

Comment: I cant simply access the original model because the user has selected filters. Those filters are saved using javascript and ajax in this model. Yet there could be many filters but I need them all. So if I were to re grab this data out of the database i would need all those filters. Such is what I am figuring out how to pass over.

Comment: Yo umentioned something about an AJAX request in your comment, but I cannot see absolutely no related code in your question whatsoever to an AJAX request. AJAX means javascript, can't see such thing in there. You could use AJAX to send values to the server but make sure that you respect the naming convention of the model binder if you expect those values to be bound back in your POST controller action.

Comment: Yes there is a form on the page that uses an external js page that has some ajax on it that takes the selected filters and then saves those back to the Model.FilterSet. This is how the user can select various filters. This is why I am desperately trying to pass that Model.FilterSet back to my controller. Otherwise i would straight query the db by project id and be done.

Comment: In this case make sure you respect the correct naming convention of the values being sent. For example if your model has a complex property called `FilterSet` which in turn has a string property called `FooBar`, this is the value that you should send in your AJAX payload: `FilterSet.FooBar=someValue`. That's how model binding works in ASP.NET MVC. And as far as collections and dictionaries are concerned, you can read more about them in the following blog post: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/ Also use a javascript debugging tool like Chrome developer toolbar.